# rollupjs dynamic require not bundling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rollupjs

I've a component library with an Atom component that have an external lib for do a specific task. This external lib (imported in this component) have a dynamic svg import like that:
`require('../flags/' + countryCode.toLowerCase() + '.svg')` and I can compile it without any error. But when I use this lib give me that error: `Can't resolve '../flags'`.

There's my rollup.config.js

```
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg'
import path from 'path'

export default {
  input: "src/index.js",
  output: {
    file: "lib/bundle.js",
    format: "cjs",
  },
  external: [
    'react', 
    'react-dom',
    'prop-types',
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    nodeResolve({
      extensions: [".jsx", ".js"],
    }),
    postcss({
      extract: true,
      namedExports: true,
      extensions: ['.sass', '.scss'],
      modules: true,
      use: [
        [
          'sass', {
            includePaths: [path.resolve('node_modules')]
          }
        ]
      ]
    }),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'runtime',
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    commonjs(),
    svg()
  ],
};
```

How I can fix this problem? I cannot change the dynamic import because it's an external lib, any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
...,
commonjs({
  dynamicRequireTargets: 'path/to/your/file'
}),
...
```